# Configure Java VM of Eclipse to run with JavaFX

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I would like to know if it is possible to configure the Java VM used by Eclipse to run in this way, that it uses JavaFX SDK libraries.

Please be aware! I don't want to build JavaFX applications on my own in Eclipse, e.g. by using E(fx)clipse or other plugins.
Another remark: I don't use Java development perspective in Eclipse or a Java project. So it won't work to add the external .jars of JavaFX as user libraries!

In my use case I have an third-party GUI application based on JavaFX that has to be started out of Eclipse.
If I try to start this application I receive the following error:

> The system reqirements are not met.
> Could not find: javafx.properties
> in:
> /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.macosx.x86_64_17.0.2.v20220201-1208/jre/lib
> Your Java Virtual Machine seems not to support JavaFX,
> required to run the XXX.
> Please make sure you provide a valid path to the Java FX
> modules during gui installation.

As you can see by the error message my Eclipse runs on a MacOS x64 system.
But I think the way to configure the VM of Eclipse should work on each system the same way.

Thank you.

Steve

Comment: Solved it on my own.

Solution:
Added following lines to eclipse.ini behind `-vmargs` parameter:
`--module-path=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/javafx-sdk-xx/lib` and `--add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH`.

Comment: If you have a third-party GUI application, why do you need an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) like Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a third-party GUI application, then you do not need an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) like Eclipse.

Ideally the publisher of your app would have provided the app as a package that includes the JavaFX/OpenJFX libraries as well as all the parts of a JDK/JVM needed to run that app on your Mac.

If the publisher gave you only the bare-bones app without the needed libraries & JDK/JVM, you can obtain a JDK/JVM bundled with those libraries.

At least two vendors supply a JDK with JavaFX/OpenJFX libraries:

- *ZuluFX* by Azul Systems
- *LibericaFX* by BellSoft

Both are available free-of-cost with optional support plans available for sale. Download either product as an installer specific to your Mac, while paying attention to either Intel-based Mac or Apple Silicon (ARM, AArch64) based Mac.

You can verify the install by using a console such as *Terminal.app* to run:

```sh
java --version
```

… and:

```sh
which java
```

You can also use the Finder to locate your installed JVMs by choosing *Go > Go to Folder…* where you paste:

```sh
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
```

If your app contains the [necessary `MANIFEST.MF` file](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/javatomac3.html), you may be able to launch your app by double-clicking. If not, use a console such as *Terminal.app* with the `java` command to launch the app.